# Rails 5 + Foreman + Pow gives me "Couldn't proxy request to localhost:5000"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, foreman, rack-pow

I'm trying to use Foreman and Pow to work with a Rails app locally. Foreman is working and I can access the app on `localhost:5000`. The problem is when I go to access `myapp.dev`, I get the pow error page with this message:

> Proxy Error
>
> Couldn't proxy request to localhost:5000.
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I know that Pow, Foreman, and Rails work on my system because I have them configured in other apps and they work fine. The only thing I can come up with for what's different between this app and ones that are working is this app uses Rails version 5.0.0rc1.

I can't just give up on Pow because one of the requirements for this app is using subdomains which I can't work with without a proper domain name.

I'm wondering if anybody else has had a similar issue with a Rails 5 app or has any clue what is going on here.

Comment: Is it a symlink mapping or a port mapping? Can you show us the contents of ~/.pow/myapp?

Comment: It is a port mapping. `cat ~/.pow/myapp` gives me `5000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar error on OS X. Using symlinking instead of the port mapping seemed to fix this, even for an app running on a seemingly random port.

```
cd ~/.pow
ln -s /path/to/myapp
```

And then go to `myapp.dev`

Comment: You might also look into using a tool called powder to make the linking easier. It also makes it easy to look at log files, restart, etc.